# How to add separate text and separate image on the one heigth [CSS/HTML]?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I wanna to set up image and paragraph on one height as I said in title. And I wanna this image to be like the same width and height with the paragraph. 
The main problem, if I tried to use my container(I don't really know if it's a container), the image goes inside the paragraph. I got a really terrible headache and didn't solve it yet. Need some help. 
This is my code + image of page that I wanna to create:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.h1_main {
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: #06FE35 1px 1px 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.pretty_1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-shadow: grey 1px 1px 15px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.container {
  border: 7px solid #01FE30;
  margin-right: 75%;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-shadow: #F40752 1px 1px 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.right_image {
  float: left;
}

.ecorp {
  text-shadow: red 1px 1px 6px;
  text-align: center;
}

.transparent {
  zoom: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: left;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.fsoc {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: red 2px 0px 0px;
}

.links {
    font-color: black;
    text-shadow: grey 1px 1px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: center;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MR.Twister</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='podstava.css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class='h1_main'>Who is </h1>
    <div class='center'>
      <a href='index.html' class='links'>Main</a>
      <a href='about.html' class='links'>&nbsp;&nbsp;About</a>
      <a href='gallery' class='links'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Galley</a>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <p class='pretty_1'>Wiki Says:</p>
    <p>
      <p class="container"> - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -<br />
      <small>Hi there Hi there</small></br />
      - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -   <br />
      You are the best thing to ever happen to me. You are the true definition of a true value. True friendship stands the test of time and you have shown me what it is to have real friends. I value your friendship and I will remain every grateful for your love. Thanks for being my friend. Cheers to our loving friendship.<font color='#6D202C'><small>E</small><small><small>Corp.</small></small></font></p>
    <div class='transparent'>
      <font class='fsoc'color='red'>all rights reserved (c)</font>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvYE4.png)

Comment: use float right for the right image ` .right-image{ float:right;
} `

Comment: didn't work, I tried, it set the image under the paragraph

Comment: where actually are u defining image? i cant see any image or its url in css or html. can you clarify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this but using the latest CSS3+ properties such as [Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) and [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid), you can create the layout you want. 
All that is needed for the flex solution is to specify the container to `width: 100%;` to make the container take full width of the page, allowing you to layout freely, set its `display: flex;` to use the `flex` property and set the `flex-direction: row;` to make the items inside the container be aligned horizontally.

Then separate the right content in a `div` and the left content in a different `div` with both being inside the container.

Refer to this fiddle, I've fixed some code issues that you have. Also, don't use the font tag as [it's not supported in HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font), use the `style` attribute instead. 
https://jsfiddle.net/9oej1z6p/

Comment: yes, that's not bad, but still not what I want. I wanna image to be separate, not in the border. I you know how to deal with this problem, would be really appreciatable!

Comment: I updated the fiddle, visit the link again for the updated preview.

Comment: Also, next time post an illustration of the desired result in order to make your question more understandable. If this fixed it for you don't forget to upvote and set this answer as the correct one!